# How to mark files to manage the diff output

Tags: diff

My collegues are maintaining a configuration file, which is deployed to production/test/staging environments by SaltStack. I am maintaining this file by using diff to see what has changed and code the appropriate jinja snippet.

The file name is `program.conf` and the SaltStack version is `program.conf.jinja`.

`program.conf` has lines of the form:

```
variable = "value"
```

`program.conf.jinja` is:

```
variable = "{{ value }}"
```

From diff's point of view, these are different. But from my point of view, they are same. I am looking for a pragma-like feature where I can say mark the jinja file as following so that I won't get that in the output of diff:

```
variable = "{{ value }}" # pragma-same: variable = "value"
```

I will also be using that utility to generate alerts to force people to update the jinja file for any missing variable.

`variable = "value"` sometimes resolve to more complex stanzas like:

```
{% if pillar.get(...) %}
variable = {{ value }}
{% else %}
variable = {{ value + 2 }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Well, now it looks even more like the thing to do is to find and/or develop some sort of compiler/validator that reads the files, checks whether they are correct, and reduces/minimizes them to a bare-bones format that can be compared directly. But I’m not sure your question still makes sense. If `program.conf.jinja` says that `oblongness` might be 17 and might be 19, what can `program.conf` say to avoid being flagged as different?

Comment: Think about the process. When someone makes a change X in program.conf, it actually means "translate change X to  program.conf.jinja". When I make the change X', I am done.

When a change Y comes in, until I make Y', I want diff to show me that I still need to translate Y to Y'.

I can wrap a relevant change in .jinja with <change for=X></change> and hope diff to detect that and if any line around those line numbers is equal to X, it will show "no change". I am aware that this won't be as simple as that for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Would you be willing to create a normalized temporary file, and compare against that?

```
sed 's/{{ \(.*\) }}/\1/' program.conf.jinja > temp  &&  diff program.conf temp
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I've updated my question with an additional complex example.